# Reference anonymous parent from anonymous child when declaring nested objects with Object Initializer

Tags: c#, object-initializers

If I have a parent, child, grandchild set of classes, where the grandchild require's it's parent as a constructor parameter, is there any way to still be able to use a nested [Object Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) declaration?

For example, consider Invoice Header, Invoice Line, Invoice Line breakdown:

```cs
public class InvoiceHeaderModel
{
    public List<InvoiceLineModel> InvoiceLineModels { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceLineModel
{
    public List<InvoiceLineBreakdown> InvoiceLineBreakdowns { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceLineBreakdown
{
    public InvoiceLineBreakdown(InvoiceLineModel parentInvoiceLine)
    {
        _parentInvoiceLine = parentInvoiceLine;
    }

    private InvoiceLineModel _parentInvoiceLine;
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is this:

```cs
public InvoiceHeaderModel BuildAnInvoice()
{
    return new InvoiceHeaderModel
    {
        InvoiceLineModels = new List<InvoiceLineModel>
        {
            new InvoiceLineModel
            {
                InvoiceLineBreakdowns = new List<InvoiceLineBreakdown>
                {
                    new InvoiceLineBreakdown(/* Need to reference the anonymous outer InvoiceLineModel*/),
                    new InvoiceLineBreakdown()
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

But I can't, as the `InvoiceLineBreakdown`'s constructor needs a reference to the anonymous `InvoiceLineModel` that contains it.

I appreciate there are good arguments for not referencing parents from children, but is there any way to achieve the nested declaration above using Object Initializers], or do I just have to explicitly declare all the objects and then compose the Invoice Header afterwards?

Comment: Are you able to edit the model classes?

Comment: C# object initializers are not perfect - this is one such example. Personally I avoid them because you can't use them with immutable types anyway.

Comment: @Sweeper: yes I can

Comment: @Dai: "Object intializers"... thank you, that's the term I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable reference.

Here is a complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ihm = new 
    {
        InvoiceLineModels = new List<Object>
        {
           new {
               Test = 1,
               //ihm = ihm Can't be used here until the declaration is completed nor can this be used.
           }
        }
    };
        //ihm is available here 
        Console.WriteLine(ihm.ToString());
    }
}
```

It seems you should separate the processes; load the children from the db and then add them to the list to be returned which can be stored in the ihm. Use the [let](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause) syntax to achieve that same thing during query.

In summary. Wheres the POF for the allocation etc. Good luck